# Android Decryption Error

Tags: java, android, encryption, public-key-encryption, private-key

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt Strings in my Android application but I keep getting an InvalidKeyException error.

Here is my code:

//Generate Keys method

```
public void generateKeys() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = cal.getTime();
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 25);
    Date end = cal.getTime();

    KeyPairGenerator kpg = null;
    try {
        kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        kpg.initialize(new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                .setAlias(KEY_ALIAS)
                .setStartDate(now)
                .setEndDate(end)
                .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(1))
                .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + KEY_ALIAS))
                .build());
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();

    KeyStore ks = null;
    try {
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        ks.load(null);
        Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    KeyStore.Entry entry = null;
    try {
        entry = ks.getEntry(KEY_ALIAS, null);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnrecoverableEntryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!(entry instanceof KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Not an instance of PrivateKeyEntry.");
    }
    else{
        privKey = ((KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) entry).getPrivateKey();
        pubKey = ((KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) entry).getCertificate().getPublicKey();
    }

}
```

//Encrypt Method

```
private String encryptString(String value){
    byte[] encodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "AndroidOpenSSL");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,  pubKey);
        encodedBytes = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Base64.encodeToString(encodedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

//Decrypt Method

```
private String decryptString(String value){
    byte[] decodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "AndroidOpenSSL");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,  privKey);
        decodedBytes = c.doFinal(Base64.decode(value, Base64.DEFAULT));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error", "Error = " + e);
        return "SECURE_FAILURE";
    }

    return new String(decodedBytes);
}
```

//Test Code

```
    generateKeys();
    String encrypted = encryptString("Hello World");
    Log.e("Encrypt", "encrypted = " + encrypted);
    String decrypted = decryptString(encrypted);
    Log.e("Decrypt", "decrypted = " + decrypted);
```

It looks like the encryption works OK as it prints out something like this:

> encrypted =
>   SbA2iWWKQbDL7NTA9xvtjD/viYDdpx9fLRYTSZ8UQzdBy3QLqzkswBY21ErH7FPza3vZys4E4PZw
>                                                                 uxaGkRz0aC0FLqsYlbpcJernGm5+D5lRcBOaZmgkNY9pMf0YP75cBbcJdcmb1rDaH40nCRDnEoXv
>                                                                 rGESJRqT6p0NMzlZqdd9KO3tqfExwgservAWxPNtRDBbMgE4I/09418jM5Ock5eayfOuv/STwEy6
>                                                                 Ecd56UjFH63h+gP6ed2aMDhBVeExMxvdloY+VnsAxS5Dkoc2GdaljtjRuPK48HQASoJK8EwAMNpz

But when I try to decrypt I get the following error:

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: Need RSA private or public key

I can't figure why I am getting this exception? Can anyone help?

Comment: Any luck? I'm getting the same exception in Android Marshmallow.

Comment: I fixed it by using a different provider... see my answer below.

Comment: Unless there is some reason for needing asymmetric encryption (RSA) public/private keys just use symmetric encryption such as AES. Symmetric encryption is the general choice for data encryption. Asymmetric encryption data length is limited to the key size and is really slow and no more secure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using a different provider, like this:

```
Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround");
```

Comment: Works for me, though some explanation would be great.

Comment: Look at the answer by 'lanna blue', you MUST change provider name for RSA encryption depending on the Android version! Otherwise you'll get errors!

Answer (score 17):

this worked for me:

```
private Cipher getCipher() {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { // below android m
            return Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "AndroidOpenSSL"); // error in android 6: InvalidKeyException: Need RSA private or public key
        }
        else { // android m and above
            return Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround"); // error in android 5: NoSuchProviderException: Provider not available: AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround
        }
    } catch(Exception exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException("getCipher: Failed to get an instance of Cipher", exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm... and what if we had created a public and a private RSA keys on, say, on Lollipop and then user upgraded his Android OS to Marshmallow. And our method will return different provider - will it work with previously generated RSA keys?

Comment: @KirillKarmazin I think if you use the same algorithm, cipher and padding, the result should always be the same, no matter what provider you use.

Comment: I also think that we can just skip the second parameter and let the provider be chosen for us

Answer (score 6):

Removing the provider worked for me:

```
Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
```

From [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getInstance(java.lang.String)): "This method traverses the list of registered security Providers, starting with the most preferred Provider. A new Cipher object encapsulating the CipherSpi implementation from the first Provider that supports the specified algorithm is returned."